# How to set "text-font" with mapbox expressioins

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-expressions

I am trying to set the font with the help of Mapbox expressions from font_size field.
This doesn't work for me (Invalid data expression for "text-font". Output values must be contained as literals within the expression)

```
 "text-font":  [
      "case",
      ['!=', ["get", "text_font"], ""],
      ["get", "text_font"],
      ['literal',['DIN Offc Pro Italic', 'Arial Unicode MS Regular']]
  ],
```

So I want to get a text-font from `text_font: ["Open Sans Semibold Italic"]` and if it is empty like
`text_font: ""` use `['DIN Offc Pro Italic', 'Arial Unicode MS Regular']`
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error message is telling you what you need to know, but don't want to hear:

> Invalid data expression for "text-font". Output values must be contained as literals within the expression.

The output values (that is, the font that is going to be set) must be specified as a literal - not derived from a feature property.

So you could do something like this as a workaround:

```js
"text-font":  [
  "match", ["get", "text_font"],
    "Open Sans Semibold Italic", ["literal", ["Open Sans Semibold Italic"]],
    "Arial", ["literal", ["Arial"]],
    // ... all possible values ...
    ['literal',['DIN Offc Pro Italic', 'Arial Unicode MS Regular']]
  ]
],
```

Comment: What about "Branch labels must be numbers or strings"?

Comment: That means that branch labels must be numbers or strings. So to make this work, either match on the first element of the font array, or don't story the fonts as arrays.

Comment: Thank you. But could you provide an example if I have a `"text_font_for_poi_label": "Open Sans Semibold Italic"` in a feature property? I am getting  Branch labels must be numbers or strings error too

Answer (score 1):

this is an old post but I've just come across a better solution while having the same problem.

You can use the format expression [as described here](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/). You'll want to use the `text-field` property rather than the `text-font` field.

Example:

```
"text-field": [
      "format",
      "Hello ",
      {
        "text-font": ["get", "text_font"],
        "text-color": "#f7f7f7",
      },
    ]
```

You can also use an expression for the color and content too, see below.

```
"text-field": [
      "format",
      ["get", "text_content"],
      {
        "text-font": ["get", "text_font"],
        "text-color": ["get", "text_color"],
      },
    ]
```